# Swapping classes on click with jQuery, by using elements class

Tags: jquery

I have written this simple bit of jQuery that swaps out the containing ul's class based on which contained anchor is clicked. It's working fine, but, I know this is messy. I was wondering if someone could point out a way to do this same effect without having to manually enter each class name. I am just a jQuery newb and am looking to learn more about it.

I imagine the there is a jQuery function I could write that wouldn't involve manually inserting every class name, but one that could just take the anchor tag's class and slap it onto the ul.

The jQuery

```
$("#infosplashnav a.news").click(function () { 
  $(this).parents("ul:eq(0)").removeClass();
  $(this).parents("ul:eq(0)").addClass("news");
});
$("#infosplashnav a.communitylife").click(function () { 
  $(this).parents("ul:eq(0)").removeClass();
  $(this).parents("ul:eq(0)").addClass("communitylife");
});
$("#infosplashnav a.youth").click(function () { 
  $(this).parents("ul:eq(0)").removeClass();
  $(this).parents("ul:eq(0)").addClass("youth");
});
```

The HTML

```
<ul id="infosplashnav" class="news">
     <li><a href="#news" class="news">News &amp; Events</a></li>
     <li><a href="#communitylife" class="communitylife">Community Life</a></li>
     <li><a href="#youth" class="youth">Youth</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("#infosplashnav a").click(function () { 
  $(this).closest("ul").removeClass().addClass($(this).attr("class"));
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, never new about .closest or using .attr in that way. Thanks! Works like a charm and makes a ton of sense.

Comment: Another +1 for 'closest'. Also on thinking of utilising the current object's class. Brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
classNames = ["news", "communityLife", "youth"];

$.each(classNames, function(n, className) {
  $("#infosplashnav a." + className).click(function () { 
    $(this).parents("ul:eq(0)").removeClass();
    $(this).parents("ul:eq(0)").addClass(className);
  });
});
```

Comment: $(this).parents("ul:eq(0)").removeClass();
    $(this).parents("ul:eq(0)").addClass(className);
this 2 lines can be $(this).parents("ul:eq(0)").removeClass().addClass(className);,
learnt a good technique from u, vp foru :-)

Comment: That seems like it's just doing the same thing a different way. Any ideas on how to get it to grab the class name of #infosplashnav a automatically and then apply that to the #infosplashnav?

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227286/get-class-list-for-element-with-jquery. This is not straightforward, because an element can have more than one classes.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget you can use chaining as well, so

```
$(this).parents("ul:eq(0)").removeClass();  
$(this).parents("ul:eq(0)").addClass("news");
```

Can become:

```
$(this).parents("ul:eq(0)").removeClass().addClass("news");
```

Comment: Forget? Never knew that that! Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Yes, certain functions return the object that is calling them, this means you can chain them together. There are also functions end() and andSelf() that help you reference other items in the chain.