# How to read different CSS classes with the same beginning with jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, sapui5

I have this structure on the page:

```
<div class="sapUiVltCell sapuiVltCell">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="skip-undefined col-1">
            <span id="__button0" class="Handler1 sapUiRb sapUiRbInteractive sapUiRbStd sapUiRbSel" tabindex="0" style="width:100%;" aria-labelledby="__button0-label" aria-disabled="false" aria-invalid="false" aria-checked="true" role="radio" data-sap-ui="__button0">
                <input id="__button0-RB" type="radio" name="sapUiRbDefaultGroup" tabindex="-1" checked="checked"></input>
                <label id="__button0-label" class="sapUiRbNoText" for="__button0-RB"></label>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="skip-undefined col-2"> . </div>
        <div class="skip-1 col-2">
            <input id="__field4" class="Handler1 sapUiTf sapUiTfBack sapUiTfBrd sapUiTfDsbl" value="" style="width: 50%; direction: inherit; text-align: left; background-color: rgb(251, 251, 251); border: 1px solid rgb(219, 219, 219);" aria-autocomplete="none" aria-multiline="false" role="textbox" aria-disabled="true" tabindex="-1" disabled="" data-sap-ui="__field4"></input>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

What is gonna happen (in theory, didnt put all the code in here, because its SAPUI5) is, that I klick on a radiobutton and I want my textfield to be enabled and the others disabled again (if one was already enabled), up until now I have this structure for the code:

```
function selectHandler2() {
    $(".Handler2").prop("disabled", false);
    $(".Handler2.sapUiTfDsbl").css({"background-color":"rgb(255, 255, 255)",
                                    "border":"1px solid rgb(191, 191, 191)",
                                    "color":"rgb(191, 191, 191)"});
    $(".Handler1, .Handler3, .Handler4, .Handler5, .Handler6, .Handler7").prop("disabled", true);
    $(".Handler1.sapUiTfDsbl, .Handler3.sapUiTfDsbl, .Handler4.sapUiTfDsbl, .Handler5.sapUiTfDsbl, .Handler6.sapUiTfDsbl, .Handler7.sapUiTfDsbl").css({"background-color":"rgb(251, 251, 251)",
                                    "border":"1px solid rgb(219, 219, 219)"});
};
```

The classes are generated by SAPUI5. I did each one of these for the 7 different RadioButtons, that activate 7 different textfields.

But now I want to automatize it to only one function selectHandler() instead of 7.

Any ideas would be great.

Comment: I believe you're looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668275/jquery-check-if-element-has-a-class-begining-with-some-string

Comment: Check out the [starts with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Comment: I didn't understand your question, basically you want to get all the elements that start with particular class name ?

Comment: @dwreck08 I need a tip how to code, so the jquery reads the class that starts with "handler" and then save the number at the end and then search through all the inputs for the ones with the same "handler" class.

Comment: @MokshShah yeah but on top of that save the number and search through the whole HTML code for a similar class with that class name

Comment: Did you mean it? _$("[class*='Handler']").on("click", function(){});_

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes thats the beginning im gonna go with

Comment: @OsamahAldoaiss Give a little search about _CSS Selector Reference_, and you will found what you can try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a click listener on the radios and using the next function:

```js
$('.row input[type="radio"]').on('click', function() {
    $('.row input[type="text"]').prop('disabled', true); //disable all text input
    $('.row input[type="radio"]').not(this).prop('checked', false); //uncheck other radio
    $(this).next('.row input[type="text"]').prop('disabled', false); //enable the current input
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div>
    <input class="handler1" type="radio"/>
    <input class="handler1" type="text" disabled="disabled"/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div>
    <input class="handler2" type="radio"/>
    <input class="handler2" type="text" disabled="disabled"/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div>
    <input class="handler3" type="radio"/>
    <input class="handler3" type="text" disabled="disabled"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### EDIT: Inputs in separate divs

```js
function ActivateInput(el) {
  $('.row input[role="textbox"]').prop('disabled', true); //disable all text input
  $(el).parent().parent().parent().find('input[role="textbox"]').prop('disabled', false); //enable the current input
}

$('.row input[type="radio"]').on('click', function() {
  ActivateInput(this);
});

ActivateInput($('.row input[type="radio"]:checked'));
```

```css
.row div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sapUiVltCell sapuiVltCell">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="skip-undefined col-1"> <span id="__button0" class="Handler1 sapUiRb sapUiRbInteractive sapUiRbStd sapUiRbSel" tabindex="0" style="width:100%;" aria-labelledby="__button0-label" aria-disabled="false" aria-invalid="false" aria-checked="true" role="radio" data-sap-ui="__button0">
            <input id="__button0-RB" type="radio" name="sapUiRbDefaultGroup" tabindex="-1" checked="checked"/>
                <label id="__button0-label" class="sapUiRbNoText" for="__button0-RB"></label>
            </span>

    </div>
    <div class="skip-undefined col-2">.</div>
    <div class="skip-1 col-2">
      <input id="__field4" class="Handler1 sapUiTf sapUiTfBack sapUiTfBrd sapUiTfDsbl" value="" style="width: 50%; direction: inherit; text-align: left; background-color: rgb(251, 251, 251); border: 1px solid rgb(219, 219, 219);" aria-autocomplete="none" aria-multiline="false"
      role="textbox" aria-disabled="true" tabindex="-1" disabled="" data-sap-ui="__field4" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="skip-undefined col-1"> <span id="__button0" class="Handler2 sapUiRb sapUiRbInteractive sapUiRbStd sapUiRbSel" tabindex="0" style="width:100%;" aria-labelledby="__button0-label" aria-disabled="false" aria-invalid="false" aria-checked="true" role="radio" data-sap-ui="__button0">
            <input id="__button0-RB" type="radio" name="sapUiRbDefaultGroup" tabindex="-1" checked="checked"/>
                <label id="__button0-label" class="sapUiRbNoText" for="__button0-RB"></label>
            </span>
    </div>
    <div class="skip-undefined col-2">.</div>
    <div class="skip-1 col-2">
      <input id="__field4" class="Handler1 sapUiTf sapUiTfBack sapUiTfBrd sapUiTfDsbl" value="" style="width: 50%; direction: inherit; text-align: left; background-color: rgb(251, 251, 251); border: 1px solid rgb(219, 219, 219);" aria-autocomplete="none" aria-multiline="false"
      role="textbox" aria-disabled="true" tabindex="-1" disabled="" data-sap-ui="__field4" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: followup question after I buil it in, If the structure of the html code is more complicated, that means when I add another div aroud the inputs or if the inputs are in different divs, how would you change the code?

Comment: your text input is not directly after the radio input?

Comment: Please put your exact generated HTML structure in your question.

Comment: exactly this is the case, because SAPUI5 renders them in different divs

Comment: @OsamahAldoaiss Amended based upon your **actual** HTML structure.

Comment: You are great, thank you. This snippet worked and I think from here on I can edit it myself if I have to.^^

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [starts with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) from jQuery:

```
$("input[class^='handler']").click(function(){
    ...
});
```

Alternatively, you could loop over all the radio inputfields with [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) and bind the event handler accordingly to the class:

```
// Loop over all radio buttons
$("input[type=radio]").each(function(){

    // Check if class starts with "handler"
    if( this.className.substr(0, 7) == "handler" ){

        // Bind event
        $(this).click(function(){
            ...
        });
    };

});
```

Comment: I want him to only pic the handler class of the clicked radiobutton, how would you change that?

Comment: Maybe using the [Starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) would be better `$("[class^=handler]")`

Comment: @RodrigoAssis that's indeed the best method. Updated my answer.

Comment: @RodrigoAssis yeah that could work to pick the handler class of the selected radiobutton

Comment: @OsamahAldoaiss You can also use `:checked` in the selector to only get the selected radio buttons.

Comment: @OsamahAldoaiss Also look at the [not](http://api.jquery.com/not/) selector, so you can do what you want with all the elements but the current one. `$("[class^=handler]").not( this ) ....`

Answer (score 0):

Listen to change on radio, get the checked radio's id, disable all fields(loop between ids), enable field with the same id :

```
var tot_handlers = 7;

// Disable all but the $'(.Handler' + id) one
function enableHandler(id) {
    // disable all fields
    for (n = 1; n <= tot_handlers; n++) {
        $('input.handler' + n + '[type=text]').prop("disabled", true).css({
            "background-color": "rgb(251, 251, 251)",
            "border": "1px solid rgb(219, 219, 219)"
        });
    }
    // enable the good field
    $('input.handler' + id + '[type=text]').prop("disabled", false).css({
        "background-color": "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
            "border": "1px solid rgb(191, 191, 191)",
            "color": "rgb(191, 191, 191)"
    });
}

// Suggestion to get id id of the checked field
$('input[type=radio][class^=handler]').on('change', function(){
    var $checkedradio = $(this), id;
   for (n = 1; n <= tot_handlers; n++) { 
       if($checkedradio.is('.handler' + n)) { id = n; break; }
   }
   enableHandler(id);
});
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/ufwkehtz/2/

Comment: You should add a name attribute to those radios.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**, How about this one, which responds to radio button clicks that have class name starting with `'handler'`:

```js
$(document).on("click", "input[class^='handler'][type='radio']", function () {
    $rb = $(this);
    var inputSelector = $rb.attr("class");
    inputSelector = "input[class='"+inputSelector+"'][type='text']";
    $input = $(inputSelector);
    if ($rb.checked == false) {
      
        $input.attr("disabled", true);
        $("input[class^='handler'][type='text']").not($input).attr("disabled", false);
        
    } else {
  
        $input.attr("disabled", false);
        $("input[class^='handler'][type='text']").not($input).attr("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div>
        <input class="handler1" type="radio" name="handler" checked></input>
        <input class="handler1" type="text" value="radio 1 input text"></input>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div>
        <input class="handler2" type="radio" name="handler"></input>
    
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div>
        <input class="handler3" type="radio" name="handler"></input>
        <input class="handler3" type="text" disabled="disabled" value="radio 3 input text"></input>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
    <input class="handler2" type="text" disabled="disabled" value="radio 2 input text"></input>
```

Comment: How would you change the code, if the two inputs are not in the same div? (Unfortunately this is how SAPUI5 renders the elements)

Comment: @OsamahAldoaiss After looking at the accepted answer, I must comment that this one works quite similarly as both answers use the next() function to identify the text element. More info: https://api.jquery.com/next/  + btw, in your question you didn't specify the requirement you just commented. Anyway, this answer was just an alternative way of doing it, and I had fun :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer it was similar yeah, but like I commented in the other answer, the SAPUI5 system makes a quite complicated rendered structure (check my question for an updated structure)

Comment: @OsamahAldoaiss cheers for the feedback, I haven't used the SAPUI5 but it looks great - I've seen the demo, but I don't know the details of it - sorry.

Comment: @OsamahAldoaiss Hi, after having a break I realized that my answer wasn't too far off from the SAPUI5 requirements, so I made some changes that might work in that environment. So I updated some parts of the code. I hope you find it okay :-)