# Use jQuery to get a list of classes

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a un-ordered (`ul`) HTML list. Each `li` item has 1 or more classes attached to it.
I want to go through this `ul` list and get all the (distinct) classes. Then from this list create a list of checkboxes whose value matches that of the class and also whose label matches that of the class.  One checkbox for each class.

What is the best way to do this using jQuery?

Comment: nothing so far. Just got the list set up. I wasn't sure where to even start.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Class List for Element with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227286/get-class-list-for-element-with-jquery)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
// get the unique list of classnames
classes = {};
$('#the_ul li').each(function() {
    $($(this).attr('class').split(' ')).each(function() { 
        if (this !== '') {
            classes[this] = this;
        }    
    });
});

//build the classnames
checkboxes = '';
for (class_name in classes) {
    checkboxes += '<label for="'+class_name+'">'+class_name+'</label><input id="'+class_name+'" type="checkbox" value="'+class_name+'" />';
};

//profit!
```

Comment: You should check whether `this` is the empty string before adding it to the list, in case there are extra spaces in the class declaration.

Comment: You need to check against `''`. If you split by a space, you will never get a space, but `'a..b'.split('.')`will give `['a', '', 'b']`

Comment: Would this only work for a list or should it work if I want to get all the different classes for tr's in a table? because it doesn't want to work for me, within the each function i get undefined for `$(this).attr('class')`

Comment: is there any way to get specific classes only? say the classes that starts with `tag-` with wildcard? thanks

Answer (score 3):

i also needed this functionality but as a plugin, thought i share it...

```
jQuery.fn.getClasses = function(){
  var ca = this.attr('class');
  var rval = [];
  if(ca && ca.length && ca.split){
    ca = jQuery.trim(ca); /* strip leading and trailing spaces */
    ca = ca.replace(/\s+/g,' '); /* remove doube spaces */
    rval = ca.split(' ');
  }
  return rval;
}
```