# What is the preferred method of retrieving class names with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

So far, I'm using

```
$(this).attr('class');
```

But I worry about compatibility because I know some browsers do some weird things with `class` and `id` attributes. Seems like a great place for jQuery to implement its own method, but I can't find it in the documentation.

<del>Isn't there a bug somewhere that has className and id acting on the same objects? This may only apply to IE setting values, or maybe I'm just misremembering.</del>

*As meder pointed out, I was thinking of `id` and `name`, not `id` and `class`.*

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227286/get-class-list-for-element-with-jquery

Comment: @Adam - he's not asking the same exact question as that "duplicate".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.attr('class')` would work out because internally it uses `className`

Comment: But I recall hearing in a talk something to the effect that IE and maybe sometimes Opera will return the class *or* id when you use className. This may only apply to assignment, though.

Comment: You could of course test this by trying to use `.attr('class')` in IE and Opera.