# Switching class between two elements using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have two elements with a class name each. And on some event I'd like them to switch class.
So basically I'd like to do something like this:

```
$("#div1").switchClassWith("#div2");

<div id="div1" class="someStylingClass">...content...</div>
<div id="div2" class="someOtherClass">...content...</div>
```

And this would result in `#div1` having `someOtherClass` as its class name, and `#div2` have `someStylingClass`... Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you know what these classes are ahead of time, or could they be anything?

Comment: suggestion: the example looks more like a swapClasses(div1, div2) than div1.switchClassWith(div2)

Comment: @Nick: Yeah, I know what the class names are going to be, so I was just looking for something easier than creating a function, which would have to create temp variables and such...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/):

```
 $('#div1,#div2').toggleClass('someStylingClass someOtherClass');
```

Assuming you start with the example you posted, where each element has one class or the other (but not both) then this will work as expected.

If you need to swap the classes without knowing what classes you're swapping, you can do:

```
var $div1 = $('#div1'), $div2 = $('#div2'), tmpClass = $div1.attr('class');
$div1.attr('class', $div2.attr('class'));
$div2.attr('class', tmpClass);
```

Comment: `.toggleClass('someStylingClass someOtherClass')` :)

Comment: It's better to cache the div1 and div2 selection. In this case you've selected both of the 2 times instead of only once.

Comment: I knew there had to be some sweet, sweet, one-liner to fix this!

Answer (score 1):

```
function SwitchClass(a,b){
  var aClass = a.attr('class');
  var bClass = b.attr('class');
  a.removeClass(aClass).addClass(bClass);
  b.removeClass(bClass).addClass(aClass);
}


SwitchClass($('div1'),$('div2'));
```

Answer (score 1):

pseudo code

```
function swapClasses(element1, element2)
{
   class1List1 = getClassList(element1)
   classList2 = getClassList(element2)

   for class in classList1
   {
       element2.addClass(class)
   }

   //similarly for element1
}

function getClassList(element)
{
   //refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227286/get-class-list-for-element-with-jquery
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery UI switchClass](http://jqueryui.com/demos/switchClass/) ?