# Can I remove just the last added class from an element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys, the question pretty much asks itself... however, for more clarity:

I have an element called "chuckPalahniuk" and it has classes named "choke", "fightclub" and "haunted".

How could I get it so when I click on the "chuckPalahniuk" element, it removes "haunted" first, then "fightclub" on the second click and "choke" on the third?

**also**: be aware that the class names are dynamically added.

Cheers. peeeps!

psy.example:

```
$('#chuckPalahniuk').click(function() {
  $(this).removeLastClassAdded(); //except this function doesn't exist...
});
```

Comment: get the class list by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227286/get-class-list-for-element-with-jquery and remove last entery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just save in an array variable `c`  every class you add `c.push('yourclass')`, then `$(this).removeClass(c.pop());`

http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/pop.html

Answer (score 2):

This will do it and will deal with leading and trailing whitespace, which a `split()`-based solution will not:

```
$('#chuckPalahniuk').click(function() {
    this.className = this.className.replace(/(^|\s+)[^\s]+(\s+)?$/, "");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
$('#chuckPalahniuk').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass($(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/).pop());
});
```