# How to use the removeClass() callback function?

Tags: jquery, regex, removeclass

since jQuery 1.4 `removeClass();` now takes a function as argument.

My `<body>` tag has a few classes added to it, for example:

```
<body class="heading-helvetica para-georgia pattern-flowers">
```

I wish to be able to replace the classnames, and I believe the function in `removeClass()` can help me, but I don't really understand [the documentation on the jQuery site](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) nor am I any good with Regex.

How can I replace for example `heading-helvetica` with `heading-myriad` or `para-georgia` with `para-times` and so on?

I had previously used something like this, which works only if the class name it is trying to replace is the first in the list of class names:

```
$('#headings li').click(function(){
    var this_class = $(this).attr('id');
    $('body[class|="heading"]').removeClass();
    $('body').addClass(this_class);
});
```

Comment: `$('something').removeClass('heading-helvetica').addClass('heading-myriad');`. Is there some reason this won't work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to get the list of classes from the `body` tag and iterate / parse them.

See this article for how to get the classes.

[Get class list for element with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227286/get-class-list-for-element-with-jquery)

You will have to figure out a list of classes to add and a list of classes to remove. Using a function as the parameter of the removeClass method isn't really necessary. Since you also need to add classes, it probably is the wrong way to go.

Comment: Pefect. I made up some variation of this and got it working nicely. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle them all, you can use `.attr()` instead. Example:

`var prev = $("body").attr('class');
$("body").attr('class', prev.replace('helvetica', 'myriad'));`

That's pretty broad though, depending on what you're doing you may be better off with `removeClass()` and `addClass()`.