# jQuery get clicked classname

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get Class List for Element with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227286/get-class-list-for-element-with-jquery)

If I have something like this, I can get the id of the clicked selector by doing this.

```
$('#one, #two, #three').click(function(){
    alert(this.id)
})
```

My question is if I have classes instead of id's, how do i get the classname of the clicked selector.

```
$('.one, .two, .three').click(function(){
    // ??????
})
```

---

***EDIT:***

*The clicked elements may have multiple classes, and I wish to isolate the class that was used to initially select the element.*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'd use the native `.className` property.

```
this.className
```

---

It's `this.className` instead of `this.class` because `class` is a reserved word in JavaScript, and some browsers haven't allowed reserved words to be used as property names.

---

It sounds like there could be multiple classes on an element. To isolate one, you can use `$.grep` with `$.inArray`.

```
var classes = ['one','two','three'];

$('.' + classes.join(',.')).click(function(){
    var classNames = this.className.split(/\s+/);
    var cls = $.grep(classNames, function(c, i) {
        return $.inArray(c, classes) !== -1;
    })[0];
    alert(cls);
});
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/rFT8j/

---

Or you could use `$.each` instead of `$.grep`.

```
var classes = ['one','two','three'];

$('.' + classes.join(',.')).click(function(){
    var classNames = this.className.split(/\s+/);
    var cls;
    $.each(classNames, function(i, c) {
        if( $.inArray(c, classes) !== -1 ) {
            cls = c;
            return false;
        }
    });
    alert(cls);
});
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/rFT8j/1/

---

If you want something a little simpler, one solution would be to take advantage of closures, and assign separate handlers that each reference a different name in the variable scope...

```
var classes = ['one','two','three'];

$.each(classes, function(i, c) {
    $('.' + c).click(function(){
        alert(c);
    });
});
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/rFT8j/3/

Comment: this className will not work if the selector have multiple classes 'like <div class="two whatever something">' All the classes of the element will be picked up

Comment: @Pinkie: `this.className.split(/\s+/);`.

Comment: How is split going to help. If i clicked on this '<div class="two whatever something">' i will get `two whatever something`. I want 'two' be be alerted and not the other classes that are not in the selector

Comment: @Pinkie: You asked *"how do i get the classname of the clicked selector"*. If you're asking how to isolate a specific class out of multiple, you need to ask that.

Comment: @Pinkie: It sounds like you're asking what selector was matched, not the class(es) on the element.

Comment: Yes rocket exactly. I want the class of the clicked selector and not anything else outside that

Comment: @Pinkie: I just updated with a solution that builds the initial selector from an Array of classes, then uses that same array along with `$.grep` and `$.inArray` to isolate the clicked one.

Comment: Thanks. This works great. I guess there is no simpler way to do this.

Comment: @Pinkie: Aside from assigning separate handlers, not really. You're ultimately searching for one of a set in another set, so there'll be some complexity. If you want a little more simplicity, you could assign a property or attribute to the element that has only that class, or you could assign separate handlers in a loop each of which will close over a different class name. I'll give an update with that last solution.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('.one, .two, .three').click(function(e){
    console.log($(e.currentTarget).attr('class'))
})
```

Comment: /facepalm  I just wrote a bunch of stuff this morning that checked with `$(...).attr('class');`  Thank you!

Comment: `class` is not a jquery method. You mean `attr("class")`.

Answer (score 5):

Just use JQuery's .attr to get the attribute class value

```
alert($(this).attr("class"));
```

Comment: Just note that elements can have multiple classes (separated by spaces).

Comment: @Rocket true.  Then I would see Tim Bolton's suggestion for doing this at [http://stackoverflow.com/a/1227309/992437](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1227309/992437)

Comment: This will not work. It outputs all classes of the element and not just the clicked class that is defined in the selector.

Answer (score 0):

The following two methods should work:

```
$('#one, #two, #three').click(function(){
    alert(this.className)
})

$('#one, #two, #three').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("class"))
})
```