# How to get all CSS classes of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element with multiple classes and I'd like to get its css classes in an array. How would I do this? Something like this:

```
var classList = $(this).allTheClasses();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Class List for Element with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227286/get-class-list-for-element-with-jquery)

Comment: duplicates are the results of different search queries. Some people will google "Get Class List for Element" and others will google "getting the css classes of an element". I did the latter, and others will too.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

No need to use jQuery for it:

```
var classList = this.className.split(' ')
```

If you for some reason want to do it from a jQuery object, those two solutions work, too:

```
var classList = $(this)[0].className.split(' ')
var classList = $(this).prop('className').split(' ')
```

Of course you could switch to overkill development mode and write a jQuery plugin for it:

```
$.fn.allTheClasses = function() {
    return this[0].className.split(' ');
}
```

Then `$(this).allTheClasses()` would give you an array containing the class names.

Comment: ok, the reason I think I need to do this in jquery is that I'm passing a jquery object as a function's parameter and using the code like this: var classList = TheObject.prop('className').split(' '); It works; is this the best way to do it?

Comment: Yes, that's the best way. The plugin would be nicer though if you use it at multiple places in your code.

Comment: ok, thanks for the code. I'll come back to the plug-in idea if I need to use this in several places.

Answer (score 25):

Note that you can also use [`myElement.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) as a simple array-like object:

```js
const classList = myElement.classList;
```

[This is supported by all major browsers for a while now, apart IE 9 and below](http://caniuse.com/classlist).

Comment: Actually classList is not an array but a [Dom token list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList) so keep in mind you can't use array methods with it straight away.

Comment: `Array.from(myElement.classList)`

Answer (score 9):

This should do the work for you:

```
var classes = $('div').attr('class').split(" ");
```

This would be the jQuery solution for other solutions there are other answers !

Answer (score 3):

Check this out:

```
var classes = $('selector').prop('classList');
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function showClasses() {
  const div = document.querySelector('div');
  const classes = div.className.split(' ');

  const p = document.querySelector('p');
  p.innerHTML = classes;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo bar">This div has foo, bar classes</div>
<p class='output'>Above div classes appear here</p>
<button onClick="showClasses();">Show div classes</button>
```

HTML

`<div class="foo bar">This div has foo, bar classes</div>`

Vanilla JavaScript. It will return an array of classes.

```
const div = document.querySelector('div');
const classes = div.className.split(" "); // ['foo', 'bar']
```

Answer (score 1):

**element.classList.value**

```js
console.log("class")
console.log(document.getElementById('c2').classList.value)
```

```html
<div id="c2" class="class1 class2"> i am two class</div>
```

getAttribute

```js
    console.log("class")
    console.log(document.getElementById('c2').getAttribute('class'))
```

```html
    <div id="c2" class="class1 class2"> i am two class</div>
```

className

```js
   console.log("class")
        console.log(document.getElementById('c2').className)
```

```html
        <div id="c2" class="class1 class2"> i am two class</div>
```

to make an array choose any one of above method

string.split(' ');