# getting class attr in jquery

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery

I have some divs that are generated dynamically with content. I add the content id to the class for the div like so:

```
<div class="div-1"></div>
<div class="div-3"></div>
<div class="div-6"></div>
<div class="div-8"></div>
```

How do I select the id for a div because I need it as a param to send via ajax. e.g. I need to get the 1 when I click on the 1st div, 3 when I click on 2nd and so on

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get all CSS classes of an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279368/how-to-get-all-css-classes-of-an-element)

Comment: I think you're confusing IDs with classes. If you switch the class="" to id="", then we're talking about IDs. You could bind $('div').click(function() {var this_ID = $(this).attr('id);  this_ID.replace('div-', ''); }); Quick, dirty and untested.

Comment: None of your divs have an id?  Do you mean how to you get the number out of the class name?

Answer (score 1):

```
var id = $(this).attr('class').replace('div-', '');
```

Or even simple

```
var id = this.className.replace('div-', '');
```

Where `this` points to the dom element you click on inside the click handler.

```
//Here instead of document it is better to specify a parent container of all divs
$(document).on('click', '[class^="div-"]', function(){
       var id = this.className.replace('div-', '');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and remember changing `"div"` for your selector:

```
$(document).on("click", "div", function() {
    var class_elem = $(this).attr("class").split("-");
    var n = class_elem[1];  // This is your number
});
```

Comment: You are not using `on` correctly, it is as good as `bind('click',...)`. This is not going to work for dynamically created elements.

Comment: I've edited it, though I don't think this is relevant for this question.

Comment: And now I read again the question, I realized the "that are generated dynamically" part, so thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The correct jQuery syntax is:

```
$("div").click( function() { 
    var id = $(this).attr('class').replace('div-', '');
});
```