# jQuery: How to check if two elements have the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, detection

Is there a way to check if two elements have the same class name? My code looks like this...

```
<body class="foo bar cats">
<a href="#" class="foo">Link</a>
<a href="#" class="puppies">Link</a>
```

What I want to do is add another class to the `foo` link if it matches a class in the body. How would I check if one of the classes in my links matches a class in the body with jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227286/get-class-list-for-element-with-jquery

Comment: You should use [.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

Comment: if ($('selector').hasClass('foo')) alert('i have class foo, wohoo');

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('a').each(
    function() {
        var classes = this.classList;
        for (var i=0,len=classes.length; i<len; i++){
            if ($('body').hasClass(classes[i])){
                $(this).addClass('bodySharesClass');
            }
        }
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/39vZ2/).

---

**Edited** to try and account for Internet Explorer's inability to understand/use/implement `.classList`:

```
if (!document.createElement().classList){
    var useAttr = true;
}

$('a').each(
    function(i) {
        var classes = [];
        if (!useAttr){            
            classes = this.classList;
        }
        else {
            classes = $(this).attr('class');
        }
        for (var i=0,len=classes.length; i<len; i++){
            if ($('body').hasClass(classes[i])){
                $(this).addClass('bodySharesClass');
            }
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/39vZ2/1/).

---

**Edited** because it appears my previous attempt, to account for IE, failed. Sigh. Still! This approach should work, albeit I can't test it, as I'm without both IE *and* Windows:

```
$('a').each(
    function(i) {
        var classes = this.className.split(/\s+/);
        for (var i=0,len=classes.length; i<len; i++){
            if ($('body').hasClass(classes[i])){
                $(this).addClass('bodySharesClass');
            }
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/39vZ2/4/).

References:

- [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.classList).
- [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/).

Comment: Thanks for the update to fix IE. It was broke in Firefox too.

Answer (score 4):

ok, assuming I understand you correctly, you can do something like this...

```
var link = $(".foo");//or select your link another way
var linkClass = link.attr("class");
if($("body").hasClass(linkClass)){
   //link has matching class
   link.addClass("newClass");
}
```

As you can see I have used the [hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) JQuery function to check if the body tab has the matching class.

---

If your link will potentially have more than one class name you can do it like this...

```
var link = $(".foo");//or select your link another way
var linkClass = link.attr("class");
var classList = linkClass.split(/\s+/);

var matchFound = false;

for(var i = 0; i < classList.length; i++){
    if($("body").hasClass(classList[i])){
       //link has matching class
       matchFound = true;
    }
}

if(matchFound){
    link.addClass("newClass");
}
```

---

Also, if you want to process all your links at the same time you could wrap it all in a [JQuery each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and change the first line like so...

```
$("a").each(function(index){
   var link = $(this);

   //the rest of the above code here
});
```

Comment: What about the link has multiple classes?

Comment: @xdazz: Apparently you didn't read this part of the linked documentation: "The .hasClass() method will return true if the class is assigned to an element, even if other classes also are."

Comment: @xdazz: The it becomes a different question. html/javascript can change so much it is pointless trying to cater for "what if's". Always better to code to your current requirements and keep the javascript as clean as possible

Comment: @Piskvor You didn't understand my mean. I mean if link has multiple classes, `link.attr("class")` will return something like `foo foo1 foo2`, so does `.hasClass()` work?

Comment: @xdazz: I probably didn't. `link.hasClass("foo1")` would still return `true` in your example (which is what the documentation says, as quoted above). Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a').hasClass('foo').addClass('whatever');
```

Answer (score 0):

using jquery hasClass() method will lead you to a solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is one suggestion, there might be others (that are better) as well :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $foo = $('.foo'); // select the foo link
    if ($(body).hasClass($foo.attr('class'))) {
        $foo.addClass('anotherClass');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var body_classes =$('body').attr('class').split(/\s+/);
var foo_link = $('a.foo');
$.each(body_classes, function(index, item){
    if (foo_link.hasClass(item)) {
       foo_link.addClass('class_you_want_to_add');
       return false; 
    }
});
```