# Select elements which have any of the classes of another element

Tags: jquery

Given an element like

```
<div class="A B"></div>
```

where the classes of the div are unknown and/or can change, 
I want to select elements like

```
<div class="A"></div>
<div class="B"></div>
<div class="A B"></div>
<div class="B Foo"></div>
```

in other words any element which has class A or B.

jQuery has the `is()` function, so I thought about grabbing the string containing the classes of the main div using `attr("class")`, prefixing each class with `.` and using `is()` to filter, but that feels like a hack.  Any way to do this elegantly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#targeted_div').click(function() {
    if (this.className) {
        var classes = $.trim(this.className).split(/\s+/);
        var matches = $('.' + classes.join(',.'));
    }
});
```

So if the classes for `'#targeted_div'` are `A B`, the selector for the matches will be `'.A,.B'`. In other words, it will select any elements that have at least one of those classes.

Comment: Probably want to use `/\s+/`, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227286/get-class-list-for-element-with-jquery

Comment: This is basically what I was thinking, though I had thought `is()` would act as a selector but its just a true/false test.  Looks good