# Get class with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Im able to get id, src, style or whatever with:

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
       console.log('id :' + e.target.id);
});
```

But I want to get the class, why isnt that possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Class List for Element with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227286/get-class-list-for-element-with-jquery) -- please [use the search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+get+element+class) before you ask a new question.

Comment: *why isnt that possible*: It is possible. Seems you must be doing something wrong. But you have not showed us *how* you are trying to get the class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
       console.log('class :' + e.target.className);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have few options

call:

```
.attr('class');
```

call:

```
target.className
```

second will return all classes so if it is `main content` it will give you string with them it is easier to use

```
.hasClass("class-name")
```

eg.

```
target.hasClass(".hidden")
```

returns true or false if element hass class or not. Most useful and reliable. Just check if it has your class of choice!

Comment: fuuuu again i'm not first to answer ;<

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jQuery for the click event why not use it to get the class attribute

```
 $(document).click(function () {
       console.log('class :' + $(this).attr("class"));
 });
```