# how to get class value of a span

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get Class List for Element with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227286/get-class-list-for-element-with-jquery)

how can i get the class value of a span inside a div?

```
<div id="Check">

<span class="checked">

<input id="box" name="INbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />1<br>

<span>

</div>
```

how to get the value of class="checked" from  on div="Check"?

and use it like this

```
<script>
var span = $('div#Outbound').find('span').attr('class');
if ( span != "checked"){

}
</script>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why not add the class to the `.find()` selector? And what do you expect `.value()` to do? There's no such jQuery method, and `.val()` doesn't work on `span` elements.

Comment: I recommend to read the documentation first before you use a method, so that you don't waste time trying things. You would also found out that there is no method with name `.value`: http://api.jquery.com/?ns0=1&s=.value

Comment: Wait, now you want to do something when it does not have the class? I think you should describe what you're ultimately trying to do. This code gives me a strong sense that you're taking the wrong approach to whatever the actual problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
var spanClass = $('div#Outbound').find('span').attr('class');
```

Or if you just want to determine if the `span` has a class named `checked`, use [`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/):

```
var hasCheckedClass = $('div#Outbound').find('span').hasClass('class');
```

Answer (score 2):

Without need for jQuery:

```
var span = document.getElementById('Check').getElementsByTagName('span')[0].className;
```

Or, if the format of the HTML is predictably "the span is the first element inside the div" then you can cheat a little:

```
var span = document.getElementById('Check').children[0].className;
```

To check if the class `checked` is on the span, you can do this:

```
if( span.match(/\bchecked\b/))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery hasClass

```
 <script>

    if ( !$('div#Outbound').find('span').hasClass( "checked" )){

    }
    </script>
```