# Can I use the classlist property to update text within divs in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use div classes to update text within the divs.

```
<div class="green paper 15">
<p class="desc">TEST 1</p>
</div>

<div class="blue rock 3">
<p class="desc">TEST 2</p>
</div>

<button value="0">COLOR</button>
<button value="1">CHOICE</button>

<script>
$("button").click(function () {
    var class_val = $(this).val();
        $.each('div', function(index, value) {
            $class_arr = $(this).classList;
            $new_desc = $class_arr[class_val];
            $('p.desc').text($new_desc);
        });
});
</script>
```

$class_arr throws an undefined error. Where am I going wrong? Thanks for your time.

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227286/get-class-list-for-element-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery does not have a classlist property.  Try obtaining the classes as follows:

```
<script>
$("button").click(function () {
    var class_val = $(this).val();
        $.each('div', function(index, value) {
            $class_arr = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
            $new_desc = $class_arr[class_val];
            $('p.desc').text($new_desc);
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: OK. Got it. Wasn't going over the div's properly:
    $('div').each(function(index)

Answer (score 0):

```
.classList  is not a valid selector..
```

Try this instead

```
$class_arr = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
```