# Find the "other" classes of an element though jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have two elements on which multiple classes are applied something like this

```
<div class="one two"></div>
<div class="one three"></div>
```

Through jQuery how can I target the other class of the element if targeted by the common class (in this case 'one')?

```
$('.one').????
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227286/get-class-list-for-element-with-jquery

Comment: Do you already know the other class names, or are they dynamically generated?

Comment: So you want to get the object's classes without the one through which you selected it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of searching I found that jQuery has a special simple function for this. I got what I needed with something like this

```
if($('.one').hasClass('two')) //do something;
if($('.one').hasClass('three')) // do something;
```

Answer (score 2):

try this to see all classes added to element

```
var classes=$('.one').attr('class').split(" ");
$.each(classes, function(index, cls){
    alert(cls);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try $('.one.two');

or

$('.one.three');