# How can i remove dynamically class names using jquery and a second class name?

Tags: jquery, class

this is my code. I want to remove a class name from tag `<p>` <=> `$i=2`. In the above code it removes the class name "test2" from all `<p>` tag. How can I do remove a class name from a specific tag if this have 2 class names. thx?

```
     <p class="test1 test2">text</p>
        <p class="test1 test2">text2</p>
        <p class="test1 test2">text3</p>
        <p class="test1 test2">text4</p>
        <p class="test1 test2">text5</p>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function test(){
    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        if  (i ==2 ){
              $(".test1" ).removeClass("test2");
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: `$(".test1" ).eq(3).removeClass("test2");`

Comment: I re-readed your question and I became confused... Do you want to remove the `test2` class from the second element, or remove the `test2` class for all the `p` elements that contain 2 classes?

Comment: I want to remove the test2 from the second element using the class name test1 also from the second element in jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

```
   $(".test1:eq(1)" ).removeClass("test2");
```

Comment: this works for me, thx . But can you explain me , what is eq()  ?

Comment: eq() selector in jquery is used to locate the DOM elements by specifying the index. It starts from 0. Since you require the second element, you have to specify the index as 1 to retrieve it. For more information, please refer this link :- http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this, You include below one inside your `<script>`

```
$(function(){
$("p").each(function(index){    
   console.log(index); 
   if(index==1){
      $(this).removeClass('test2');
    }
  });    
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/D5JwH/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
$("p").removeClass().addClass("test2");
```

What it does is simply remove both classes and add the one u want to keep

Answer (score 0):

There, I fixed it for you:

```
<p class="test1 test2">text</p>
<p class="test1 test2">text2</p>
<p class="test1 test2">text3</p>
<p class="test1 test2">text4</p>
<p class="test1 test2">text5</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".test1:nth-child(2)" ).removeClass("test2");
</script>
```

What was wrong, was that you propably tried to run js code as if it was PHP

Javascript has to be included in `<script>` html tags and is executed the moment the browser receives it

Also, the code inside your loop was meaning: 'get all the elements with class test1 and remove the class test2 from them', so no matter what part of the loop the code gets executed on, all of the `.test1` elements will loose their `.test2` class.

The `:nth-child(2)` part of the jquery means 'get all the `.test1` elements but only if they are the second child of their parent'.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the following script:

```
;!(function ($) {
$.fn.classes = function (callback) {
    var classes = [];
    $.each(this, function (i, v) {
        var splitClassName = v.className.split(/\s+/);
        for (var j in splitClassName) {
            var className = splitClassName[j];
            if (-1 === classes.indexOf(className)) {
                classes.push(className);
            }
        }
    });
    if ('function' === typeof callback) {
        for (var i in classes) {
            callback(classes[i]);
        }
    }
    return classes;
};
})(jQuery);
```

and then use it

```
$('div').classes();
```

It will return collection of classes assigned to the element.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227286/get-class-list-for-element-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

```
<p class="test1 test2">text</p>
<p class="test1 test2">text2</p>
<p class="test1 test2">text3</p>
<p class="test1 test2">text4</p>
<p class="test1 test2">text5</p>
<?php
var i=1;
$('p').each(function(index){
if (index == 2){
           $(this ).removeClass("test2");
      }
i=i+1;
}); 
?>
```