# getting a specific class name of an element with multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Lets say I have this in my html:

```
<div id="myDiv" class="a b-32"/>
```

I'm trying to get the index of 'b' class (in my example '32')

The only way I know how to do it is by:

```
var index;
var myDiv = $("#myDiv").attr("class");
var classes = myDiv.split(' ');
for(var i=0; i<classes.size(); i++){
    if(classes[i].matches((b-)+[\d]*) ){
        index = classes[i].replace("b-","");
    }
}
alert(index);
```

Is there any solution that doesn't imply iterating all the classes manually? Because my solution seems dull. Surely there must be a better way, I just can't find it.

Comment: Question is NOT a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227286/get-class-list-for-element-with-jquery

Comment: Why you using int dataType inside for loop ... do you think Is it right in jQuery

Comment: @kamesh what do you mean?

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin: Re kamesh's comment, you have `for(int i =0...` in your question. As this is JS, that should be `var` (or `let` in ES6).

Comment: @T.j.Crowder thank that what i try to say

Comment: oh, sorry :)) java habbit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Y'know, for all that people claim jQuery makes it so you have to write less code, [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) is surprisingly good at one-liners :p

```
alert((document.getElementById('myDiv').className
                                         .match(/(?:^| )b-(\d+)/) || [0,0])[1]);
```

(Whitespace added for readability)

Returns `0` in the event where `myDiv` doesn't have a `b-number` class.

EDIT: As @A.Wolff pointed out in a comment on your question, you may wish to consider this:

```
<div id="myDiv" class="a" data-b="32"></div>
```

Then you can get:

```
alert(document.getElementById('myDiv').getAttribute("data-b"));
```

Comment: Beware using `\b` with classes, there are several characters that are valid in class names that `\b` treats as word boundaries, `-` being the most problematic.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder How's that? Better now?

Comment: `className.match(/(b-\d+)/g)[0].substr(2)`

Comment: @pawel: That fails to account for `class="somethingunrelatedb-32"`

Comment: Oh, that data-* attribute is even better and solves a lot of problems.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: I suppose. I'm not a huge fan of the `|| [0,0]` thing, but there's nothing really wrong with it. The change kinda makes my answer retroactively a dupe. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Whoops :p Yeah, I'm not a huge fan of it either, but a well-commented one-liner can be better than the lengthy alternative. But `data-` is best here ^_^

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: Agreed a `data-*` is the much better choice. I don't see any particular value in one-liners. They usually lack clarity, are hard to debug, and encourage things like the `|| [0,0]`.

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression can help:

```
var index;
var myDivClasses = $("#myDiv").attr("class");
var cls = myDivClasses.match(/(?:^| )b-(\d+)(?:$| )/);
if (cls) {
    index = cls[1];
}
```

(Use `parseInt` if you want it as a number.)

That looks for `b-###` where `###` is one or more digits, with either whitespace or a boundary (start of string, end of string) on either side, and extracts the digits.