# iterate through classes on same element

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a div which has multiple classes assigned to the `class` attribute, is it possible to iterate through them using the `each()` function in jQuery?

```
<div class="class1 differentclassname anotherclassname"><div>
```

Comment: Something like `$('div').prop('className').split(' ').forEach(fn)`?

Comment: @undefined I've updated my question as I forgot to state that I don't know the class names that'll be used as they're placed dynmacially

Comment: @CurtisCrewe - That shouldn't affect what undefined said (you're splitting the className property, and then forEaching through the list. Should work fine (even if you don't know the class names before)

Comment: Why do you need jQuery? `element.className.split(' ').forEach(...)` will work in every browser that supports *forEach*, and it's easy to [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) those that don't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get class list for element with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227286/get-class-list-for-element-with-jquery)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In JavaScript, to get the list of classes, you can use

- `.className.split(' ')`, returns an `Array`
- (HTML5) [`.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList), returns a `DOMTokenList`

In jQuery, you can use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to get `className` or `classList` properties.

To iterate them, you can use:

- A [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop, e.g. `for(var i=0; i<classes.length; ++i)`
- (ES6) A [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList#Specification) loop, e.g. `for(var cl of classes)`.
- (ES5) [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), only for arrays, e.g. `classes.forEach(fn)`
- (jQuery) [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), e.g. `$.each(classes, fn)`

If you use `classList` but want to iterate using `forEach`, you can convert the `DOMTokenList` into an `Array` using

- `[].slice.call(classes)`
- (ES6) `Array.from(classes)`

Comment: Keep in mind that forEach in javascript is IE9+, I always get caught using it and I'm stumped as to why my code's broken in older browsers. +1 for a detailed answer :)

Comment: So which prop() is proper?  `.prop('class')` or `.prop('className')` or `.prop('classList')`

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone Use `.prop("className")` or `.attr("class")` to get a space-separated string. Or `.prop("classList")` to get a DOMTokenList.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to get an string that contains the classes with:

```
$('div').attr('class');
```

and split it with blank spaces to get an array with:

```
$('div).attr('class').split(' ');
```

and then use that array as the first argument to an $.each function where the index and the value can help you to handle it independently

```
$.each($('div').attr('class').split(' '), function(index, value) {
    console.log('Class name ' + value);
});
```

Comment: Better:  `$('div).attr('class').split('\s+');` In case the class attribute has multiple consecutive spaces, or other whitespace characters.