# Make an array with all classes of an SVG element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, svg

I know this may look like a repost, but I am not able to get the code to work that the community made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227286/get-class-list-for-element-with-jquery).

What I am trying to do is make an array of all the classes listed in the element I am clicking on. 
The element I am clicking on is a `<g></g>` element from a SVG object.

I would like to post the classes (in an array) to a modal and the ID of the `<g>` element. Here is my code:

```
//reveal Modal when when clicking on an item box.
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.items').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/includes/functions/choose_item.php",
            data: { id: this.id, class: this.className}
        })
            .done(function() {
                $('#choose_item_modal').foundation('reveal', 'open', "/includes/functions/choose_item.php") ;
            })
    });
});
```

It post it to my PHP script, and the ID works, but the class is in an array of baseval and animval, and I would like an array of all values of the baseval only.

This is the array I get:

```
Array ( [animVal] => items hero_item [baseVal] => items hero_item )
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVG elements doesn't really have classes like regular elements, and the `className` property returns a special object, usually a `SVGAnimatedString` looking like

```
{animVal: "class class2", baseVal: "class class2"}
```

The `class` attribute is really just a regular attribute with some strangeness, so you need to use `getAttribute('class')` instead, or in jQuery `attr()` to get the value of the attribute

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.items').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url  : "/includes/functions/choose_item.php",
            data : { 
                id      : this.id, 
                'class' : $(this).attr('class')
            }
        }).done(function() {
            $('#choose_item_modal').foundation('reveal', 'open', "/includes/functions/choose_item.php") ;
        });
    });
});
```

note that `class` is a keyword in javascript, so it should be quoted.
If you need an array, you can do `$(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);`

[**TEST**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/zsL0fruv/)

Comment: Ah wauw thank you alot! 
That worked perfectly, and I did not know that about classes. Great thing that you explained that out.

Comment: SVG elements can have a class attribute just like any regular element, but it's true that it was exposed in a different way in the DOM (unfortunate historical mistake). I think the solution here is fine, an alternative that exists in most recent browsers is the newer API [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList), it works the same on both svg and html elements.