# How can I get the attribute of an HTML element in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have more class in 1 div:

```
 <div class=" class1 class2 class3> content </div>
```

how can i get 1 class: ex class 2 in this div. thanks!

Comment: [get-class-list-for-element-with-jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227286/get-class-list-for-element-with-jquery)

Comment: Many browsers will already support the classList property, e.g. `$('div').prop('classList')[1];`

Answer (score 2):

You can use split like this:

```
alert($('#yourDivID').attr('class').split(' ')[1]);
```

To get all classes, you can do this instead:

```
var classes = $('#yourDivID').attr('class').split(' ');

for(var i=0; i<classes.length; i++){
  alert(classes[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#divId').attr('class').split(" ")[1]
```

Comment: thank y a lot. i done well

Comment: @HuỳnhTú Make sure to accept the answer