# Multiple images on the page and showing success text from ajax under each image

Tags: html, ajax

I have multiple images on the page. Every image has option "add to favorites". **Everything work just fine except the message that is showing above image if image is added or not to favorites**.

Success/Fail message is showing on top above first image only. I know that I must use unique id for each image but I can't understand how exactly.

Here is the HTML part where I show the images.

```
echo '
<article class="main-post" id="'.$row['image_id'].'" >
    <div class="article-top">
        <hr />
        <h1><a href="imagePreview.php?image_id='.$row['image_id'].'">'.$row['image_caption'].'</a></h1>
        <div class="counters-line">
           <div class="pull-left">
              <span id="message_favorites"></span>
           </div>
           <div id="'.$row['image_id'].'" class="pull-right">
               <div class="buttons-bar">
                  <div class="buttons">                             
                     <a href="javascript:;" class="bookmarked has-tooltip" data-title="Add to Favorites" id="'.$row['image_id'].'"></a>                                              
                  </div>
               </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="article-content">                                
           <figure>    
             <a href="imagePreview.php?id='.$row['image_id'].'"><img class="lazy" data-original="upload/'.$row['image_name'].'" alt="'.$row['image_name'].'"/></a>
           </figure>
        </div>
     </div>
</article>';
```

This snippet is in loop and show images from DB. I have added `id="$row['image_id']" to the`` so this way each article has now unique ID.

The success message is showing here

```
<div class="pull-left">
    <span id="message_favorites"></span>
</div>
```

And this is the ajax function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.bookmarked', $('.buttons')).click(function(){
    $.post('misc/add_favorites.php', 
    { 
        "image_id": $(this).attr('id'),
    },
    function(data){
        if(data == 0){
            $('#message_favorites').html('<div id="alertFadeOut" style="color: green">Added to favorites!</div>');
             $('#alertFadeOut').fadeOut(3000, function () {
                $('#alertFadeOut').text('');
             }); 
        }
        else {
             $('#message_favorites').html('<div id="alertFadeOut" style="color: green">It's already in favorites!</div>');
             $('#alertFadeOut').fadeOut(3000, function () {
                $('#alertFadeOut').text('');
             }); 
        }
     });
});
});
```

ajax part send data to `add_favorites.php` which save image id and user id into DB.

So how exactly I can show this message on the image which is clicked?

UPDATE
Ajax

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('.bookmarked', $('.buttons')).click(function(){
    $.post('misc/add_favorites.php', 
    { 
        "image_id": $(this).attr('id'),
    },
    var classes = $(this).attr('class');        //fetch all classes of the clicked item (this is a string)
//alert('The classes: '+classes);
    var classarray = classes.split(' ');        //split the string into it parts seperated by "blank"
    $.each(classarray, function(index, item){       // execute this for every subpart
    //alert(index+' '+item);
    if(index==2)            // since the third (better: use regexp) subpart stores the id-information...
    {
        //alert(item);
            $('#message_favorites').html('<div id="alertFadeOut" style="color: green">Added to favorites!</div>');
             $('#alertFadeOut').fadeOut(3000, function () {
                $('#alertFadeOut').text('');
             });            
    }
        else {
             $('#message_favorites').html('<div id="alertFadeOut" style="color: green">It's already in favorites!</div>');
             $('#alertFadeOut').fadeOut(3000, function () {
                $('#alertFadeOut').text('');
             }); 
        }        
});         
});
});
```

HTML

```
    echo '
<article class="main-post" id="'.$row['image_id'].'" >
    <div class="article-top">
        <hr />
        <h1><a href="imagePreview.php?image_id='.$row['image_id'].'">'.$row['image_caption'].'</a></h1>
        <div class="counters-line">
           <div class="pull-left">
              <div id="'.$row['image_id'].'"><span id="message_favorites"></span></div>
           </div>
           <div id="'.$row['image_id'].'" class="pull-right">
               <div class="buttons-bar">
                  <div class="buttons">                             
                     <a href="javascript:;" class="bookmarked has-tooltip '.$row['image_id'].'" data-title="Add to Favorites" id="'.$row['image_id'].'"></a>                                              
                  </div>
               </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="article-content">                                
           <figure>    
             <a href="imagePreview.php?id='.$row['image_id'].'"><img class="lazy" data-original="upload/'.$row['image_name'].'" alt="'.$row['image_name'].'"/></a>
           </figure>
        </div>
     </div>
</article>';
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to add the ID-number to the button as well (as class):

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="bookmarked has-tooltip '.$row['image_id'].'" 
   data-title="Add to Favorites" id="'.$row['image_id'].'">
</a>
```

Then use the context of the ajax request and the query `attr()` method to get the list of classes of the button (see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax). With split (see [Get class list for element with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227286/get-class-list-for-element-with-jquery)) you can then extract the ID and use it to address the correct object...

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ojk8kdg9/5/

Comment: Thank's for the answer. Can you provide with some example in my case because I'm really new in ajax/jquery and don't understand it quite well yet.

Comment: I updated my answer - I modified the setting a little bit not using ajax as well as a fixed id (id-2) (used wrong url first, sry, now it's correct!)

Comment: Just one question and I will try it. This `js` part it is part of the my current ajax or this is separated?

Comment: This doesn't seems to work as must. It's still showing the message at the first image..

Comment: The "click"-function should trigger the ajax request (i added some comments to the code). Can you post your "new" js-code?

Comment: But why to user this `id-2`? Why not image_id

Comment: id-2 is just a example. you should replace this with your image_id delivered by php. I just wrote "id-2" because I didn't care about the ajax part (since it seems that you understand this part and it's working). I just wanted to show you how you can an example of how you can get and use the id to adress the correct element to insert the message in.

Comment: Yes, I've replaced it with `image_id`. I've updated my question with how is looking now. I don't have message at all. And it didn't save into database now.

Comment: ok, please take car to use the post-function correctly (see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/). the code I suggested has to be placed in the success-function.

Comment: I've got this error now `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`