# Select elements whose class ends with particular string

Tags: javascript, jquery

This has probably been answered before but I don't know how to phrase it properly.

For elements:

```
<div id='div1' class="class1 1foobar"></div>
<div id='div2' class="class1 class2 2foobar"></div>
```

How do I get the NAME of the class ending with 'foobar'? So for 'div1' I want to get a string '1foobar' and for 'div2' I want to get string '2foobar'.

Comment: check out [get-class-list-for-element-with-jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227286/get-class-list-for-element-with-jquery)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Select all the elements whose `class` attribute value contains the required string. `$('[class*="foobar"]')` selector will select all the elements for which `foobar` is anywhere in the `class` attribute value.
2. `filter` the elements with the class name ending with it. Using `filter()` and RegEx `/foobar\b/` will filter out the elements whose class/es ends with *foobar* string.

Note that `\b` in the regex is [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

```js
$('[class*="foobar"]').filter(function() {
    return /foobar\b/.test($(this).attr('class'));
}).css('background', 'green');
```

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class2 2foob ar"></div>
<div id='div1' class="class1 1foobar"></div>
<div id='div2' class="class1 class2 2foobar"></div>

<div class="class1 class2 2foo bar"></div>
```

---

To get the class name list

1. Select elements containing `foobar` anywhere in the `class` attribute value.
2. Use `match()` to get the className, if it contains it.
3. `match()` will return `null` if no match is found in the string, else it'll return an array containing matches. The first item(*at zero-th index*) is the interested classname.

```js
$('[class*="foobar"]').each(function () {
    var className = $(this).attr('class').match(/\S*foobar\b/i);
    if (className) {
        console.log(className[0]);
    }
});
```

```js
$('[class*="foobar"]').each(function() {
  var className = $(this).attr('class').match(/\S*foobar\b/i);
  if (className) {
    console.log(className[0]);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class2 2foob ar"></div>
<div id='div1' class="class1 1foobar"></div>
<div id='div2' class="class1 class2 2foobar"></div>

<div class="class1 class2 2foo bar"></div>
```