# Can you use getElementByClassName to get a class you added with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you use getElementByClassName to get a class you added with jquery? I added a class with jquery but i can't seem to retrieve it using getElementByClassName. When I console log classList.value all I get is header. Yet when I console log classList i can see this:
[image]

Just curious if it is possible to target it. I tried to get classList.list(1) but it comes back as null.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import jQuery from 'jquery';
import $ from 'jquery';

export default class ProjectsHeader extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
         super()
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        let head = $(".header");
        let stick = "sticky";

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            $(window).scrollTop() > 400
                ? head.addClass(stick)
                : head.removeClass(stick)
        })

     let projHead = document.getElementById("projHead");




     console.log(projHead.classList);
     console.log(projHead.classList.value);

   }

     render() {
        return (
            <div id="projHead" className="header">
                <div className="not-sticky-div">
                   <div>"This is My Projects Page" McGill</div>
                </div>
                <div className="hidden-span">
                    <span>Something1</span>
                    <span>Something2</span>
                    <span>Something3</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Short answer: yes. Assuming you mean `getElementsByClassName()` (element**s** plural).

Comment: do you get any errors in console? - I believe the function is called `getElementsByClassname (...)` (plural elements) - and it returns an array of elements - *BTW* the code posted does not make a call to `getElementsByClassname(...)` so please post an [mcve]

Comment: did you try projHead = $("#projHead"); ? . also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227286/get-class-list-for-element-with-jquery

Comment: Syam yeah I did. If I console.log($(projHead)[0].classList); I get the image that in the discription. However, if I   console.log($(projHead)[1].classList); I get( Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't see it in the console because you are logging it before you add the class.

You are adding the class when you scroll to a position greater than 400px, but you are logging the class list as soon as your component gets mounted. Try to move your `console.log` to your scroll event's callback.

Also remember that JavaScript events are asynchronous, so even if somehow they are triggered before your `componentDidMount` function finishes executing, your callback won't be called until the call stack gets empty.

Great talk about JavaScript's Event Loop: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

And off-topic advice: Try to get rid of jQuery if you are using React ;)

Comment: Yeah, I was just trying to practice using jquery. I'm still new to development. But I will take your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to target it by adding this line of code. [image]