# Javascript - read all classes from an element with a unique class

Tags: javascript

I want to find with Javascript an element by class name. This class is unique. I try to do this with 
var element = document.getElementByClassName('uniqueclass')

This element have two classes (uniqueclass and element-x). I want to get the other class and work with this class as String. I tried this with various functions (classname.split, ...), but I don't find a solution.

Can anybody help me? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1227309/4361743

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get class list for element with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227286/get-class-list-for-element-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the node, retrieve the classList of the node and filter them by your term:

```
var uniqueClassName = 'unique'; // What is your unique className?

var element = document.querySelector('.' + uniqueClassName); // Fetch the element
var filterClassList = function (class) {
  return class !== uniqueClassName; // Differs the className from the unique one?
};

var classList = element.classList.filter(filterClassList); // Filter the classList via filter function
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it in right way.

Few changes

```
element = document.getElementsByClassName('uniqueclass')[0];
```

It is `Elements` not `Element` and it return a HTML Collection. Since this class name is unique, use index [0].

To get other classses of this element,

```
class = element.getAttribute('class');
```

Now class contains `"uniqueclass element-x"`