# Is it possible to get a 'css selector tree' for a string ... using Javascript or Java

Tags: javascript, java, python, css, css-selectors

I'd like to get a minimal CSS tree (not sure if that's correct term) for specific String of text.

By CSS tree I mean a set of selectors that will identify that particular text (or anything at the same level -- if there's a list of items with the same CSS then it's ok to get them all).

So for example let's say we have the following HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="someDivs">
      <div class="a-row">My text</div> 
      <div class="a-row">Your text</div>
    </div>
    <div id="someOtherDivs">
      <div class="main-div">Some other text</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I specified the input as `My text` then the `minimal css tree` would be just `.a-row` (this will match more than one item, but that's ok).

However if the HTML looked like:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="someDivs">
      <div class="a-row">My text</div> 
      <div class="a-row">Your text</div>
    </div>
    <div id="someOtherDivs">
      <div class="main-div">
        <div class="a-row">Some other text</div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then the minimal CSS tree for the input `My text` would be `#someDivs,.a-row`

I think Javascript would be the easiest, but I'm pretty technology agnostic, if there's a better way to do this using backend tech (pref Java, but python etc are fine too) then that is not prob.

EDIT: The important thing is I'm trying to get the actual textual value of the selectors and not just get a variable (in JS) that can be used to select those items.

Comment: If you are open to using jQuery, you can leverage 
 [the :contains() selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).

Comment: Yep Query is ok, I'll start playing around with that, seems the only option available so far :)

Comment: As @JorgeValle pointed out this is possible with jQuery `$(".a-row:contains('My text')").addClass( "foo bar" );` and then you can style `.foo` and `.bar` normally in your CSS sheet. here's basic JsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1s742L1c/

Comment: @Ihazkode the key thing is I don't want to style the CSS, I want to get the actual values of the selectors as text so I can store for future use. Also `.a-row:contains` because I don't know what the HTML/css is ahead of time, only the text that's on the page.

Comment: Aha, now I see what you mean. This might be of help https://stackoverflow.com/a/11232541/8157693

Comment: Oh great, thanks for this @Ihazkode. Now just need to traverse and get parents and check for 'minimality', back to work :) thx again

Comment: If it's useful for anyone else in the future, I'm also playing with JSoup which has a :contains selector and .parent() method that looks they could be useful - if doing it on the server.

Comment: No worries, glad you got it sorted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153827/discussion-between-ankur-and-i-haz-kode).