# jQuery - How to remove all classes except the first

Tags: jquery, class

I have some td elements (about 500) with multiple classes. How can I remove all but the first, knowing that this one may be different?

```
<td class"one tv-fox blue">value1</td>
<td class"two tv-cnn">value2</td>
<td class"grey tv-axn green">value3</td>
<td class"red tv-sky">value4</td>
```

**Expected result**

```
<td class"one">value1</td>
<td class"two">value2</td>
<td class"grey">value3</td>
<td class"red">value4</td>
```

Regards,
Elio Fernandes

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227286/get-class-list-for-element-with-jquery) shows you how to get a list of classes. You can use `removeClass` on all but the first result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```
var $tds = $('.myTable td');
$.each($tds, function(index, td) {
   var classNames = td.className.split(' ');
   classNames.shift()

   $(td).removeClass(classNames.join(' '));
});
```