# Selecting a class from a div with multiple classes and add it as id?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to select a class from a div which has multiple classes and print it as id.

Current Code:

```
<div class="name  usrname1  views-row">
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-user-name">
    <div class="field-content">John</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="name  usrname2  views-row">
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-user-name">
    <div class="field-content">Jane</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this code, I need to make the "usrname1" and make it id. That class dynamically changes and will be unique.

What I need:

```
<div class="name  usrname1  views-row" id="usrname1">
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-user-name">
    <div class="field-content">John</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="name  usrname2  views-row" id="usrname2>
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-user-name">
    <div class="field-content">Jane</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/farhanmae/agx6t0wy/1/

Comment: [StackOverflow isn't here to do your work for you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Show us what you have tried so far. We'll gladly help you.

Comment: To do this would involve splitting the `className` attribute by string and retrieving the second item in that array. It's incredibly brittle code which could be broken far too easily to be a workable solution. Could you explain why you believe you need this, as I'm certain there's a better way to do what you require.

Comment: follow this url
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227286/get-class-list-for-element-with-jquery

Comment: @RahulSahu I am able to get the class and pass it as id. But the id is passed to all the divs irrespective of the class its having. https://jsfiddle.net/farhanmae/wef0g6j2/1/

Comment: @Zenoo this is what i have done so far 
https://jsfiddle.net/farhanmae/wef0g6j2/1/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan what i am trying to do is by adding the id to the divs i can use it as anchor links from different sections.

Answer (score 0):

That is the best solution I was able to find.

Loop through all the `divs` searching for a `div` with the class `usrname`. When found, add it to the `id` of the selected `div`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* Loop through all divs */
  $("div").each(function() {
    var divElem = $(this) ;
    var cls = $(this).attr("class") ; //Get the div classes
    
    /* If class has the string "usrname" */
    if (cls.indexOf("usrname") !== -1) {
      var clsArr = cls.split(" ") ; //Split the cls string into an array holding all the classes.
      
      /* Loop through the array */
      clsArr.forEach(function(clsName) {
          /* If class has the string "usrname" */
          if (clsName.indexOf("usrname") !== -1) {
            divElem.attr("id", clsName) ; //Add the class to the id of the selected div
          }
      });
    }
  }) ;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="name usrname1 views-row">
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-user-name">
    <div class="field-content">John</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="name usrname2 views-row">
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-user-name">
    <div class="field-content">Jane</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

From [jQuery Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) use this: `$("[class*='username']")` to select all objects with class which contains word username. (I think it will select even if it has `username[number]` ) and after that you can user `$.each` to iterate through that array and change `id` with word do you want from class. You can do something like `object.id = object.class.indexOf('username')` or you can use split.