# How to display HTML class of current node in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have variables which:

- display the result (`result`), and
- reference the current node (`thisNode`).

What do I need to change in my code so that it would display the HTML class?

```
var thisNode = document.body.firstChild;
var result   = document.getElementById("resultOfButton");

result.InnerHTML = thisNode.; 

/* Here, in JS are there any ways like displaying the class name, 
like nodeClass */
```

Please give recommendations for my code. There may be some errors. Thank you.

```
var thisNode = document.body.firstChild;
var result = document.getElementById("resultOfButton");
var block = false;

function buttonDown()
  {
  if(block == true)
    {
    thisNode = thisNode.parentElement.firstChild;
    block    = false;
    }
  thisNode = thisNode.nextSibling;
  result.innerHTML = thisNode.nodeName;
  if(thisNode == thisNode.parentNode.lastChild)
    {
    block = true
    }
  }
function buttonUp()  
  { 
  // not done now...     
  }
function buttonEnter()
  {
  thisNode = thisNode.firstChild;
  result.innerHTML = thisNode.c;
  }
function buttonBack()
  { 
  // not done now...     
  }
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a "CSS class". Are you asking what HTML classes apply to an element? What CSS rules apply to an element? What CSS rule-sets apply to an element or something else?

Comment: [Pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) are not very helpful. Put a [mcve] in the question itself. The editor has buttons and [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to help you format it so it is readable. Provide a [live demo](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) if you're asking about HTML/JavaScript/CSS.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227286/get-class-list-for-element-with-jquery

Comment: Re edit: Please read the previous comments. Don't just link to *another* picture. Don't ignore questions in comment asking you to clarify exactly what you want.

Comment: please provide real code not picture of your code, use MarkDown syntax

Comment: I cut out everything that is not needed. Thank you very much for your changes ...(If something goes wrong I will correct)

Comment: Anything else ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking for the `className` attribute. I copied your first sample and added some code so you can run it on this page. You'll get the second emoji replaced by the class name of the inserted element.

```js
var thisNode = document.getElementById("thisNode"); // document.body.firstChild;
var result = document.getElementById("resultOfButton");
result.innerHTML = thisNode.className; /*Here, in JS are there any ways like displaying the class name, like nodeClass*/
```

```html
<div id="thisNode" class="sample-class"></div>
<div id="resultOfButton"></div>
```

Quoting [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className):
"The className property of the Element interface gets and sets the value of the class attribute of the specified element."

Comment: Thanks and yes, I already understand this (about className), just my autocomplete VScode did not show me this...